# Can't get the text correctly over TCP

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I know my title is not good but I did not know how to write this problem. I'm receiving a XML over tcp connection but the problem is the string is full of "\0" so I can't see the message when I use that string variable. I can do string.length and see It's filled but can't reach the text. I've tried replace method and it worked but I know this is not the correct solution. So here is my question how can I receive the text correctly?

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(Convert.ToInt16(_Port));
tcpListener.Start();

while (true)
{
    Socket handlerSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
    if (handlerSocket.Connected)
    {
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(handlerSocket);
        byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[102400000];
        int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

        string myCompleteMessage = "";

        do
        {
            numberOfBytesRead = networkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
            myCompleteMessage += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myReadBuffer,
        }
        while (networkStream.DataAvailable);

        Console.WriteLine("Text: "+myCompleteMessage);

    }
}
```

I've tried to change the Encoding.UTF8 to Encoding.ASCII and Encoding.UNICODE but it did not worked.

Update: My problem is still continue, the data I receive has "\0" before every character. I couldn't find why.. I use replace and inserting \0 again once I want to send data back. Can this be because of some sort of encoding? I've tried getEncodings aswell and tried many code pages but non work

Comment: TCP doesn't do messaging. It does an endless stream of bytes. It's up to *you* to work out how to communicate the length of your "message" (in this case, the complete XML file) from the other end.This could be e.g. by prefixing the length onto the start of the message, or by using some form of delimiter that won't be encountered in the message. Also, you cannot reassembly UTF 8 like that (ASCII should be okay) because you might receive the first `m` bytes of a character in one buffer and the remaining `n` bytes of the character in the next buffer full.

Comment: `DataAvailable` being `false` only tells you that there's nothing left locally available to deliver to you - not that the other end has finished transmitting.

Comment: Damien I've understand what you mean, I've used replace method for now to receive the data but I think my receive method is wrong. The application I'm trying to communicate is not mine so I don't know how he sends or receive the data. I've tried many things to receive the message but couldn't. Currently I'm trying to send back a message but seems like the program does not accept it because I couldn't establish connection with it. I mean I send succesfully but the program's connection status is not changing.

Comment: Based on your update - you originally stated "string is full of "\0"" which I took to mean that the buffer was *entirely* filled with `\0`. Now that you've clarified that it's *every other character*, then it's likely that the other end disagrees on the encoding that is being used (it's doing UTF16 a.k.a UNICODE unless it's doing UTF16BE which is also possible, and the characters in question fall within the ASCII range)

Answer (score 0):

It turns all the "\0"'s inside my string was because the data I receive was encoded with BigEndian.. when I used

```
myCompleteMessage += Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
```

everything worked well. Wanted to share this here in case if someone receive the same problem.

Comment: UTF is a multibyte encoding. There's no guarantee your buffer contains all valid characters; there could be a partial character at the beginning or end of your buffer.

Comment: I'm not so good at this, I recently learned how to communicate over TCP.. The program I'm trying to communicate is a third part program so I don't know which encoding its using, all I know is when I encode the data with BigEndianUnicode I get the data correctly and also when I send the data with converting it into BigEndianUnicode the program works well. I tried many ways to encode my message like utf-8, utf-7, unicode and many Turkish code pages(Since I want to transfer Turkish characters) and none worked. Then I realized \0 are actually empty bytes(Saw it in wireshark) and looked deeper

Comment: then I saw when I type something in english first byte is empty and the data is only in second byte but when I type something turkish like 'ş' or 'ı' the data I send had no empty bytes. After that I just searched which encodings are sending empty bytes and found bigendian.. Looks like BigEndian is not just for Turkish it also support many character sets in many language